# Scater r plotHeatmap change column annotation color

Tags: r, annotations, pheatmap

I'm trying to change annotation color, but after trying multiple parameters I still couldn't figure out how it passes the values of color in that function.

```
library(scRNAseq)
library(scater)
sceM <- MuraroPancreasData()
b<-c("CAMK2N1__chr1" , "GNAS__chr20" , "MAP1B__chr5" ,  "IDS__chrX" ,  "CPE__chr4"  , "HADH__chr4"  )
```

default color is like this, which works well.

```
plotHeatmap(sceM, order_columns_by="label", features=b)
```

assign annotation manually, but still gives me default colors.

```
newCols <- colorRampPalette(grDevices::rainbow(length(unique(sceM$label))))
mycolors <- newCols(length(unique(sceM$label)))
names(mycolors) <- unique(sceM$label)
mycolors <- list(mycolors = mycolors)
plotHeatmap(sceM, order_columns_by="label", features=b,column_annotation_colours  = mycolors)
```

parameters I tried includes `column_annotation_colours`, `colour_columns_by`. I also try to dig up the raw codes from *scater* package `plotHeatmap` [function](https://github.com/alanocallaghan/scater/blob/devel/R/plotHeatmap.R#L33) , but not really understand where went wrong.

Thank you in advance for any comments/suggestions.